# How to check if an employee is the manager of a department at the department's latest effective date?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I have trouble coding a condition in a view in SQL Oracle.

I have 2 tables, here are the names of the fields that you need:

```
EMPLOYEE_TBL (employee_id)
DEPARTMENT_TBL (department_id, manager_id, effective_date, active_status)
```

I have to code the following condition in a SELECT CASE:

```
FLAG = 'Y' if the employee is the manager of AT LEAST ONE department at the department's 
       latest (max) effective date and that the department has active_status = 'A' 
       at its max effective date
FLAG = 'N' otherwise
```

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_ID, B.EFFECTIVE_DATE, B.ACTIVE_STATUS, 
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Z.MANAGER_ID FROM DEPARTMENT_TBL Z 
                    WHERE Z.MANAGER_ID = B.MANAGER_ID
                      AND Z.DEPARTMENT_ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
                      AND Z.MANAGER_ID = A.EMPLOYEE_ID /* this is the condition */
                      AND Z.EFFECTIVE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(Y.EFFECTIVE_DATE) 
                                              FROM DEPARTMENT_TBL Y 
                                              WHERE Y.DEPARTMENT_ID = Z.DEPARTMENT_ID 
                                              AND Y.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= SYSDATE)
                      AND Z.ACTIVE_STATUS = 'A')
 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS FLAG
FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL A LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT_TBL B 
ON A.employee_id = B.manager_id
```

Here is the SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/241d99/1

**REMAINING ISSUE**: The FLAG for EMPLOYEE 35 needs to be 'Y' because he is the manager of the department D7777 at the max effective date of the department.

Here is the DEPARTMENT_TBL:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    MANAGER_ID    EFFECTIVE_DATE     EFFECTIVE_STATUS
 D1273            35            2006-01-01              A
 D1273            35            2011-12-21              A  -- here flag of 35 is 'N'
 D1273            04            2012-03-05              A
 D1000            04            2012-12-12              A
 D7777            04            2009-05-14              A 
 D7777            35            2011-09-26              A -- but here flag of 35 is 'Y'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You're right, but that will only return the employees who are managers, when I want to return all employees and just have the flag indicate whether or not they're still managers

Comment: @jpw I just found another issue. Please check the edits I made to the original post and the new SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to get the most recent record for the department.  This simplifies the query a lot:

```
select e.*,
       (case when d.department_id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as isManager
from employee_tbl e left join
     (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by d.department_id
                                order by d.effective_date desc) as seqnum
      from department_tbl d
      where d.effective_date < sysdate
     ) d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id and d.active_status = 'A' and
        seqnum = 1;
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/241d99/15) the SQL Fiddle with the typo fixed.

Comment: @jpw . . . That is easily added into the `on` clause.

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in your query with the d.effective_status... Check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/241d99/4

Comment: Just change `d.effective_status` to `d.active_status`  

     on e.department_id = d.department_id and d.active_status = 'A' and
        seqnum = 1